# CodeIgniter num_rows and affected_rows context

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This may be a bit dumb question, but I don't get this:

I have these 2 functions in my model

```
public function count()
{
    return $this->db->num_rows();
}

public function changes()
{
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

When I call `changes();` in my controller, it displays the affected rows for the last (update) query. When I use `count();` however for displaying the rows for the last (select) query, I get an error..

Code in controller is like this:

```
if (!$this->synchronization_model->get_contact_knowledge($contact['account_id'], SERVER_LOCATION_ID)) {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to update knowledge");
                    }

                    if( $this->synchronization_model->count() == 0) {
                        $this->synchronization_model->insert_knowledge($contact['account_id'], $contact_server_time);
                    }
```

Is there any way to fix or workaround to this?

Comment: where is the query executed, for which `$store->count()` is trying to count rows?

Comment: Sorry, old piece of code.. it is meant to read $this->synchronization_model->count()

Comment: Based on your new piece of code, I have updated my answer. I think that will help you fix the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed this properly.

Instead of this function:

```
public function check_account_already_exists($email_address)
{
    if ($query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM account WHERE email_address = ?', array($email_address)))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have this function:

```
public function check_account_already_exists($email_address)
{
    if ($query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM account WHERE email_address = ?', array($email_address)))
    {
        return $query;
    }
}
```

So when I call it in my controller:

```
 // Check whether the e-mail address has not already been taken
        if (!($count = $this->account_model->check_account_already_exists($email_address))) {
          throw new Exception("Failed to fetch account");
        }

       $this->account_model->count($count);
```

I can use it like that.. This way the if statement above it will still work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

`num_rows()` is not a method of the `db` class. It should be called against the `resultset` object.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
echo $query->num_rows();
```

As you see here we are not calling `$this->db->num_rows()` instead we are calling `$query->num_rows();`

As a work around you can pass the query object to the `count()` method like so:

```
public function count($query)
{
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your updated code, I suggest the following:

I assume that the query is executed in `synchronization_model`. In that case what you should do is. Have a variable in `synchronization_model` say `row_count`. And put the value of what `num_rows()` return into this variable. The in the `count()`  just return this variable. So it will be something like:

Inside `synchronization_model`:

```
......
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
$this->row_count = $query->num_rows();
......    
public function count()
{
    return $this->row_count;
}
......
```

Comment: There is nothing about passing efficiently in this context, really. If I were you, I would not write a separate `count()` function for it. Because the life/use of the function is only immediately after the query is executed. So I would just directly call `$query->num_rows()` after query execution and be done with it.

Comment: If I would do that, and there are no rows, my first piece of code would fail (see above) because num_rows would return 0 which is equal to false.

Comment: Seems quite good, found another solution though. Maybe even better because I don't need to rewrite alot of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->num_rows();
```

is returning the nnumber of rows that the result has fetched when selecting, you will need the use this as

```
   $query = $this->db->get('table');

             OR           

   $query = $this->db->query('select * from table');
   $query->num_rows();
```

`return $this->db->affected_rows();`

is returning the rows affected when you Update ,delete or insert

and where is the relevant code so that we may see it.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, the `num_rows()` function is a method of the query object, not the database object ... see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

For instance, you would use `num_rows()` in the following manner:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = 'blah'");

if($query->num_rows()){
    //yay, data!
} else {
    //no data for you
}
```

Comment: But what if I want/need different functions in my class for selecting and counting?